# How to create a Joomla 4 Quickstart package

Tags: joomla-4.x

What are the key points of creating a Joomla 4 quickstart package? It seems that the way we used to do it for Joomla 3 does not work. We were creating a Joomla 3 quickstart following these steps:

- Export db (except finder users user notes etc. db tables)
- Change table prefix to #__
- Localise your sql

Quick start packages created with this old way fail when trying to install. When inspecting the Joomla 4 installation folder, we see 3 different sql files base.sql, extensions.sql and supports.sql. What is different for Joomla 4?

---

I really need help on this topic. Does anyone know how to create a Joomla 4 quickstart except for Akeeba option? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With a little help of Akeeba Backup component, you do this very easy.

- Install Akeeba Backup
- Go to Akeeba Backup Profile Configuration and choose "**ZIP format**" from Archiver engine.
- Save and Create a new backup.

Comment: Thanks marian I know Akeeba and I will use it if  I could not find the answer.

Comment: I really need help on this topic. Does anyone know how to create a Joomla 4 quickstart except for Akeeba option? Thanks in advance.